# Trying to download a file from aws s3 into nodejs writeStream

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to download a file from s3 and directly put into into a file on the filesystem using a writeStream in nodejs. This is my code:

```
downloadFile = function(bucketName, fileName, localFileName) {
    //Donwload the file
    var bucket = new AWS.S3({
        params: { Bucket: bucketName },
        signatureVersion: 'v4'
    });
    var file = require('fs').createWriteStream(localFileName);
    var request = bucket.getObject({ Key: fileName });
    request.createReadStream().pipe(file);
    request.send();
    return request.promise();
}
```

Running this function I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: write after end
```

What is happening? Is the file closed before the write is finished? Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey
}),
file = fs.createWriteStream(localFileName);
s3
.getObject({
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: fileName
})
.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
})
.on('httpData', function (chunk) {
    file.write(chunk);
})
.on('httpDone', function () {
    file.end();
})
.send();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks that of course helps. But I am still wondering why my example fails. Is there a efficiency difference between the two versions (my one and the one in this answer?)

Comment: How do you handle the error ```No sich file or directory```?

Answer (score 4):

Also AWS notes an example of using promises like this:

```
const s3 = new aws.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
const params = { Bucket: 'yourBucket', Key: 'yourKey' };
const file = require('fs').createWriteStream('./local_file_path');

const s3Promise = s3.getObject(params).promise();

s3Promise.then((data) => {
  file.write(data.Body, () => {
    file.end();
    fooCallbackFunction();
  });
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

This works perfect for me.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html

EDIT: (15 Feb 2018) Updated the code, as you have to end the write stream ([file.end()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/stream.html#stream_writable_end_chunk_encoding_callback)).

Answer (score 0):

I have combined the above response with a typical `gunzip` operation in pipe:

```
            var s3DestFile = "./archive.gz";
            var s3UnzippedFile    = './deflated.csv';

            var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();
            var file = fs.createWriteStream( s3DestFile );
            s3.getObject({ Bucket: Bucket, Key: Key })
            .on('error', function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            })
            .on('httpData', function (chunk) {
                file.write(chunk);
            })
            .on('httpDone', function () {
                file.end();

                console.log("downloaded file to" + s3DestFile);
                fs.createReadStream( s3DestFile )
                .on('error', console.error)
                .on('end', () => {
                    console.log("deflated to "+s3UnzippedFile)
                })
                .pipe(gunzip)
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream( s3UnzippedFile ))
            })
            .send();
```